# admin.py: "model = Thing" ,what does this code mean?if without it what gonna happen?

Tags: django, django-admin

every one,,I am reading a Django practice book,,I saw a code "model = Thing" in admin.py,,,however, when I remove "model = Thing",,,the web program still can run,the admin site looks no difference??,what does this code mean?if without it what gonna happen? my models.py class is Thing

> admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from collection.models import Thing



class ThingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Thing   #if I remove this code, the program still can run,,why need this code
    list_display = ('name', 'description',)
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('name',)}
```

admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)

> modles.py

```
from django.db import models

class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

Comment: It's only required for `InlineModelAdmin` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.model

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a `model` attribute on the `ModelAdmin` class will have no effect. You can safely remove that line from your code.

In the Django admin, you specify the model when you call `admin.site.register()`, or by using the `register` decorator. This allows you to use the same model admin class for more than one model.

```
admin.site.register(Thing, ThingAdmin)
admin.site.register(OtherThing, ThingAdmin)
```

As Jon pointed out in the comments, you do need to specify the `model` for [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.InlineModelAdmin.model) objects.